# VB.NET: DYNAMICALLY ADD ARRAY TO COMBOBOX

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox, foreach, load

Does anyone know how to dynamically add an array to a bunch of comboboxes in VB.net? I could really use the help (I've been struggling with this all day). When I try to do it my way I get an error on form load.

**My code:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim MyArray() as String = {"a","b","c"}

    For each ctl as ComboBox in Me.Controls
        if ctl.tag = "yadda" then ctl.Items.AddRange(MyArray)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Error**: "Unable to cast object of type '...Button' to type '...Combobox'."

I've tried so many variations to this code but I just can't get it to work. I will eventually have nearly a hundred similarly constructed comboboxes in my application, and I'd like to be able to programmatically initialize their items. Could someone please help?

Thanks,

Elias

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to do it :

```
Public Class Form1

    Function getControl(ByVal controlName As String) As Control
        Dim numCtrls = Me.Controls.Count()
        For I As Integer = 0 To numCtrls - 1
            If Me.Controls.Item(I).Name = controlName Then
                If TypeOf Me.Controls.Item(I) Is ComboBox Then
                    Return CType(Me.Controls(controlName), ComboBox)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim myArray As Array = {"a", "b", "c"}
        Dim myComboBox As ComboBox

        For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
                If ctl.Tag = "yadda" Then
                    myComboBox = getControl(ctl.Name)
                    myComboBox.Items.AddRange(myArray)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

You loop through all controls (buttons, combo, etc ...) then you check if it is the type you want (ComboBox) and do whatever you need.

Good luck !

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error when I do it that way. **Error: 'items' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.** I get blue squiggly lines beneath "ctl.items". It seems to not recognize ctl as a ComboBox. The program won't even run.

Comment: @Elias
my bad ... :-)
you should change "If TypeOf cntrl Is" to "If TypeOf ctl Is".  I've updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, well, that wasn't the problem. I noticed the minor typo when you originally wrote it. The problem is that VS2012 won't compile the code because it won't recognize "ctl" as a combobox. I am still experiencing this issue.

Comment: @Elias Hi again, Sorry for that, my VB.Net i a little rusty ... :-)
Anyways - the problem is that even though VB recognize "ctl" as a ComboBox, it doesn't get get an instance of the control itself, but a string. Please check the revised code, it works for me.
If this also works for you - please mark this as "answered" so other may benefit from it. Good luck !